# QGIS 2.8.1 ogr OpenFileGDB zip format

Tags: qgis, ogr, file-geodatabase

I am experimenting with the OGR OpenFileGDB zip file format in QGIS 2.8.1 on Windows 8.1 x64 and although OGR says it can happily read the format (with a couple of Code Page warnings) I am unable to load the data into QGIS -

> C:\Data\Vector>ogrinfo -ro -so data.gdb.zip
>
> Warning 1: Recode from CP_OEMCP to UTF-8 failed with the error: "No
>   such file or  directory". 
>   Warning 1: Recode from CP_OEMCP to UTF-8 failed with the error: "No error". Warning 1: Recode from CP_OEMCP to UTF-8 failed with the error: "No error".
>
> INFO: Open of `data.gdb.zip'
>         using driver`OpenFileGDB' successful.
>
> 1: Cadastral_data (Multi Polygon)
>
> 2: State_controlled_roads_surveyed_centreline (3D Multi Line String)
>
> 3: Survey_Control (Point) 4: Coastline_and_State_border (Multi Line String)

In QGIS using the Add vector Layer and VSI ogr filehandler/driver I am able to select the data.gdb.zip file, but the dialog then responds with -

[image: Invalid Data Source]

I am guessing the Warnings are serious enough to make the datasource invalid, so I tried creating a new zipped, FileGDB using OGR2OGR on a simple SHP file but I get the same error.

I am able to load the raw/unzipped gdb directory successfully using either the ESRI FileGDB or OpenFileGDB driver.

Would anyone be able to recommend a solution please ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, QGIS can't load FileGDB using either the ESRI FileGDB API or the OpenFileGDB driver from a zip file, even though GDAL supports reading datasets via the /vsizip/ method.

Loading datasets from a zip file is something that needs to be coded into QGIS. Feel free to open a feature request if one doesn't exist already =)

Your dataset is probably valid and the warning you see is a generic one.

Just unzip the dataset and you can load it into QGIS then.

If you know python then it may be possible to develop a plugin to do what you want as well.

Comment: I had a search of the QGIS Feature Requests and took note of this one related to reading KMZ layers - [link](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/5242) . I followed Alisters lead and was able to load the layer by manually editing a .QGS file and updating the datasource to /vsizip/C:/Data/Vector/protareas.gdb.zip/protareas.gdb and hey presto - it works. Certainly I'd love to try and take the next step and get it into a plugin or just extend the OGR driver somehow (if its not already being done).

Comment: @ShaunK Nice find, good to know =)